# How can I import npm modules (Front End)?

Tags: npm

I always used npm to import backend modules. 
Now, I see that you can import front-end modules as jquery, ChartJS etc.

In backend I can import modules with require("MyModule"), how can I import the frontend modules?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Browsers don't natively support `require` like Node.js does.

However, [browserify](http://browserify.org/) is a tool that will bundle your code containing `require` statements into a single JS bundle that you can load in the browser via a `<script>` tag.